# Как сделать чтобы данные вставлялись рядом а не друг под другом?

Tags: mysql

Нужно чтобы выглядело так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
insert into test_1(id, title) values (1,'vaya');
insert into test_1(id, title) values (2,'lll');

insert into test_2(id, title) values (1,'ivan');
insert into test_2(id, title) values (2,'222');

insert into test_3(id, title) values (1,'ivan');
insert into test_3(id, title) values (2,'222');

INSERT INTO `main` (`t1_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_1`;
INSERT INTO `main` (`t2_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_2`;
INSERT INTO `main` (`t3_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_3`;

select * from main;
```

Что я делаю не так, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: ошибок нет никакх. любой запрос с вставкой данных дает такой результат. Например у меня так: INSERT INTO `main` (`t1_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_1`;
INSERT INTO `main` (`t2_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_2`;
INSERT INTO `main` (`t3_id`) SELECT (`id`) FROM `test_3`;

Comment: перепишите свой insert так, чтобы вставлялись сразу все нужные данные в столбцы

Comment: Как? У меня в любом случае вставляются они так. Только если писать условия where и указывать конкретную ячейку или вписывать конкретные значения, но мне это не подходит

Comment: такой вариант тоже не годится:INSERT INTO `main` (`t1_id`, `t2_id`, `t3_id`)
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
from test_1 as t1
join test_2 as t2
join test_3 as t3;

Comment: INSERT INTO `main` (`t1_id`, `t2_id`, `t3_id`) 
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id  
FROM `test_1` t1 inner join `test_2` t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 inner join `test_3` t3 on t1.id = t3.id

Comment: спасибо большое. это то что нужно!

Comment: пометьте ответ как верный, если он вам помог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO main (t1_id, t2_id, t3_id) 
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id 
FROM 
    test_1 t1 inner join test_2 t2 
       on t1.id = t2.id 
    inner join test_3 t3 
       on t1.id = t3.id
```